# How to write a program in C which counts the number of characters between the '_' characters?

Tags: c, string

- Problem 1- For the input: "All_I_Need_", the correspondent output is: 3 1 4.
- Problem 2- For the input: "All_I_Need", the correspondent output is the same: 3 1 4
- Problem 3- For the input: "All_", the correspondent output is : 3
- Problem 4- For the input: "All", the correspondent output is the same: 3

Although my code solves problem 1, giving me the correct output: 3 1 4, in problem 2, it gives me: 3 1 0 0 0 0. In the same way, my code solves problem 3, giving me the right output: 3, but for problem 4, it gives me the output: 0 0 0

```
int password_numbers(const char *s){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
    {
        if(s[i] != '_')
        {
            count++;
        }

        else
            return count;
    }
    return 0;
}

int array_password_numbers(int *a, int n, char *s){
    int result = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int streak;
    while( i < strlen(s) ){
        streak = password_numbers(s + i);
        a[result++] = streak;
        i+=streak + 1;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Are you required to handle two `_` in a row, so that `All_I__Need_` should return `3, 1, 0, 4`? If not, you can treat `streak == 0` as the end, and break out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    if(s[i] == '_')
    {
        printf("%d ", count);
        count = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ++count;
    }
}
if(count > 0)
{
    printf("%d", count);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `i < strlen(s)`, use `s[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: You're right, let's avoid computing the string length every time. I even think it is the `n` in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. All you missed is what password_numbers() should return if _ is NOT present in s. If that is the case then you are at the end of your original string and there is no terminating _. Therefore you should return strlen(s) instead of 0. With that change your code will work correctly.